# Handling HTTP responses from libcurl over multiple callbacks

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I'm using libcurl to send HTTP post requests and subsequently process the responses. Upon a response being received the library calls back to my program using the function given to the `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` property via `curl_easy_setopt`.

```
// callback function
std::size_t on_data(const char* buffer, const std::size_t size, const std::size_t nmemb, void* context);
```

It's unclear from the documentation wither you can leave data on the buffer (by returning 0 from the callback) or wither you have to copy the data to a local buffer and then continue appending to this on each subsequent callback until you have received the entire message.

My questions are:

1. What is the best way to get the entire message length; is it from the `Content-Length` header via `CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER`?
2. Is there a way to avoid copying partial responses, instead waiting for the final message to be received and then processing this in it's entirety?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as the `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` option is concerned the documentation explicitly states that this function must:

> [r]eturn the number of bytes actually taken care of.
>       If that amount differs from the amount passed to your function,
>       it'll signal an error to the library. This will abort the transfer
>       and return CURLE_WRITE_ERROR.

So unless you want to explicitly abort the transfer you should always return the real size, i.e. `size * nmemb`. Also if you choose to work with a local buffer, then yes, you have to take care to copy the incoming data into it (and take care of reallocation) as illustrated by the `docs/examples/getinmemory.c` sample code.

Please note that if you do not want to use an in-memory buffer you can also use a file via the `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` option, as illustrated e.g. by `docs/examples/url2file.c` or `docs/examples/fopen.c` examples.

Otherwise:

1. I would say that to check a priori what's the size of the resource you're willing to fetch, then you should perform a `HEAD` request (via `CURLOPT_NOBODY` set to 1 and `CURLOPT_HEADER` set to 1 too) asking for the HTTP headers to be written via `CURLOPT_WRITEHEADER` and `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` and at last parse the `Content-Length` value. But: this is definitely **not** the way to go with a `POST` request as it is not idempotent!
2. Here again if you are not comfortable with working with a growing in-memory buffer (e.g. maybe because you expect very large responses), then you should use the ability to work with files with `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` so that the response is progressively written on-disk. Once done, then use your file - that contains the entire message, the way you want.

Comment: Firstly, thanks. Writing to file isn't an option, I'm streaming real-time market data so latency (despite the vendor choosing HTTP for delivery) is important. For (1) surely a single `POST` request returns a single response and therefore a single `Content-Length`? Surely the idempotency would only result from mutliple requests? For (2) I presume this means there is no way to leave data on the buffer owned by libcurl and copy on a later callback?

Comment: (1) to be clear I think that the `HEAD` option here is not an option... right because you need to perform a `POST` and not a `GET` :/ (2) I'm not aware of such a possibility and there is no such thing exposed within the `curl_easy_getinfo` API (cf. [doc](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_getinfo.html)). The question is, if you don't want to work with files, why would you want to avoid using an in-memory buffer and write into it on-the-fly (which is a *nominal* use case)? If you properly pre-allocate your buffer (to avoid too many reallocs) there should be no performance penalty IMHO.

Comment: On reflection I think memcpy'ing into a pre-allocated buffer should be OK. In terms of (1) I'm still not clear why `POST` means `HEAD` isn't suitable, a header is returned after all. For (2) the `CURLINFO_CONTENT_LENGTH_DOWNLOAD` looks very usable.

Comment: (1) `POST`-ing a first time, reading the header for content length, and re-`POST`-ing is definitely not a clever option + you may face problems vs idempotency. Performing a `HEAD` request should simply not be possible in most cases, e.g. w/ RESTful endpoints or just because you need to effectively post something to get a proper response (but here again it depends on your web service). (2) you should not need it if you work with your in-memory buffer (BTW try to pre-allocate it with a realistic size vs your typical response sizes).

Comment: I think I understand the slight source of confusion - I had planned to have a `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION` and `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` called back on a single `POST`. I see now that this won't be necessary given when all the data has been received the `curl_easy_perform` will return and the internal buffer will be available with all the data.